# Angular material autocomplete results list is displaying behind the modal?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, mat-autocomplete

I have `modal` in which i have `angular-material` `autocomplete`. It's html is like this

```html
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width dummy-input-field" floatLabel="never">
    <input matInput class="custom-input" (blur)="getValue()" [matAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="stateCtrl">
</mat-form-field>
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" style="z-index: 2000;">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let state of filteredStates | async" [value]="state.name">
        <img class="example-option-img" aria-hidden [src]="state.flag" height="25">
        <span>{{state.name}}</span> |
        <small>Population: {{state.population}}</small>
    </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

But issue here is that my `autocomplete` results list is showing behind modal like this

[image]

You can see at the top left behind screen overlay there is a list showing. Basically this list is of `material-autcomplete` suggestion list. I have tried these css to change `z-index` of `autocomplete`

```
 .md-autocomplete-suggestions-container {
   z-index: 100000 !important;
 }
 .cdk-overlay-container {
   z-index: 999999 !important;
 }
```

But none of the solution is working. I am not using `bootstrap` moda. I am using `npm` `simple-modal`. How can i fix this issue?

Comment: Can you provide us a minimal example in stack-blitz

Comment: try giving position relative or absolute to your autocomplete div

Answer (score 4):

in your scss or css file of component add below

```
/deep/ .cdk-overlay-container { z-index: 9999; }
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to get the bootstrap's z-index dynamically and increment it with some arbitrary number and set to the time-picket something like below:

```
$(document).on('show.bs.modal', '.modal', function (event) {
  const zIndex = 1045 + (10 * $('.modal:visible').length);
  // this zIndex can be assigned to the time-picker
  $(this).css('z-index', zIndex);
  setTimeout(function () {
    $('.modal-backdrop').not('.modal-stack').css('z-index', zIndex - 1).addClass('modal-stack');
  }, 0);
});
```

This will solve your problem, but I suggest to use only one UI lib for the design :)

Comment: i am using material because it gives `angular` version of `auto-complete`

Comment: Good! try the solution and let me know if it works.

Comment: did you include classes in your answer related to `bootstrap` modal? if yes so i am not using bootstrap modal. I am using `npm` `simple-modal` so will your solution work now?

Comment: You should also replace the constant `1045` to the z-index of your modal.